# Play video live from InputStream without save the file on SD card

Tags: android, video-streaming, inputstream, android-videoview, exoplayer

What is the way in Android to play video live when i get continuously InputStream from my server?  (file format Mp4)
I don't want to save it to the SD card, I just want to play it once I get the InputStream...

Comment: Have your server serve the content [using an appropriate network protocol](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html#network).

Comment: My network protocols is web socket, what should i have to do?

Comment: Switch to one of [the supported media streaming network protocols](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html#network).